# removing single quote from end of a string in C#

Tags: c#

i am using the following code :

```
  importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().TrimEnd('$')
```

to remove a dollar from string stored in importTabs Array list. how do i pass a parameter along with '$' so that it removes a single quote (') from the beginning ans well the end of the string?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you pls fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use another trim:

```
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim('\'').TrimEnd('$')
```

Or, if you don't mind removing the `$` at the beginning too, you can do it all at once:

```
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim('\'', '$')
```

That saves you from creating one more string instance than you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I would use trim twice

```
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim('\'').TrimEnd('$')
```

Comment: seems I was beaten to this question :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understand your question.  Are you wanting to remove single quotes from the beginning and end and remove the $ from the end? If so you can use this...

```
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().TrimEnd('$').Trim('\''))
```

If the $ sign is before the ending tic mark then the Trims need to be reversed...

```
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()).Trim('\'').TrimEnd('$')
```

If you know there is not a $ sign at the beginning you can simplify it...

```
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim('$', '\''))
```

If you want to pass it in as a parameter the Trim takes an array of characters

```
char[] charactersToRemove = new[] {'$', '\''};
importTabs.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim(charactersToRemove))
```